# Is it possible to optimize redux excessive renderings on atomic state changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a complexe `react`/`redux`/`@reduxjs/toolkit` app which has many nested (on each other) react functional components (i'm using hooks and i'm new with redux)

I noticed an excessive amount rendering of these nested components for the smallest/atomic data update.
As an example , i have a grid inside of which many columns and rows. The grid model (the data)
is a kind of array of each of its rows :

```
[
 {rowId:'001', values:{col1Id:val1, col2Id:val2, col3Id:val3}},
 {rowId:'002', values:{col1Id:val4, col2Id:val5, col3Id:val6}}
]
```

When i update one of my grid cell values, the whole grid component renders many times as consequence! The grid i'm using is a third-party component which needs more stability where it's used. I'm getting some functional issues now because of those multiple renderings.

To try understand better redux behaviour, i've made [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-convert-todos-example-forked-38675?file=/src/features/todos/Todo.js) (which is based on the [@reduxjs/toolkit's todo example](https://codesandbox.io/s/uqqy3?file=/src/index.js:92-110))

When a todo label is edited , i also noticed that the whole `TodoList` is rendered as well (see logs on console as in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z32Ih.gif) )

In my app, i've tried to use the react `memo` hook to reduce the number of rendernigs of my grid component (same as the `shouldComponentUpdate` react lifecycle method) but it's not working as it seems the whole hirerchy in my app is also being rendered as well (its parent is re-rendered too)

I wish to know why not only the concerned component is rendering instead (if only the grid renders and not any of its ancestors , `memo` will work). If only a cell value changes , why at least only the grid component renders and nothing else?! Is there a way to optimize those renderings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by storing the array of ids (required for rendering `TodoList` and the actual values (required for the `ListItem`s) separately.

The tutorial chapter [Performance and Normalizing Data](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-6-performance-normalization) goes deep into that topic.